# Materialize modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I wrote a simple code for materialize modal.
**HTML code:**

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn view" data-target="modal1">View Scores</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  /*$('.view').click(function (){
    $('#modal1').modal('open'); 
    alert('edskjcxnm');
  });*/
  /*$('.view').leanModal();*/
  $('#modal1').modal('open');
});
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/7f6hmgcf/
Why isn't it working?

Comment: It isn't working in my case

Comment: Can you explain what errors you are getting and what steps you have taken to determine the problem? I don't want to replicate work you have already done.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Initialize all modals first. `$('.modal').modal();`

Complete code will look like this

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {

        //initialize all modals           
        $('.modal').modal();

        //now you can open modal from code
        $('#modal1').modal('open');

        //or by click on trigger
        $('.trigger-modal').modal();

    }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

Comment: great answer. version 0.98 doesn't seem to automatically call the modal initialization like it is opt in only. so you need to manually do it

Answer (score 6):

Not 100% sure what you are asking for here, but if what you are asking is how to trigger modal on button click you can simply do it by setting an onclick like this:

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn view" onclick="$('#modal1').modal('open');">View Scores</a>
```

But before you can do $('#modal1').modal('open'); you need to initiate the modal in your js, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal1').modal();
});
```

You can check out my solution in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreasMolle/7f6hmgcf/13/

Another solution might be to do it this way:

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn view" href="#modal1">View Scores</a>
```

Comment: Simplicity at its best

Answer (score 4):

MaterializeCCS documents aren't too clear, here's how I solved my problem.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn  modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that   wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

Comment: It isn't working for me... I'm getting this error: `TypeError: $(...).leanModal is not a function`

Comment: I figured it out, I was using version `0.98`, when I downgraded to version '0.96', it worked

Answer (score 2):

I recently updated my project to materializecss 0.98.0 and with this version I need to initialize modals before open it.

```
//Old
$('#modal1').openModal();

//New
$('#modal1').modal().modal('open');
```

I don't find any configuration like "autoOpen" on the modal initial options :(.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
  $('#modal1').on('click', function() {
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/juands/z512cb7f/3/ check this link

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? Why would this fix the OP's problem? When providing an answer you need to explain what you are providing not just leave a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try Materialize.Modal class

```
let modal=new Materialize.Modal($("#yourModal"));

modal.open(); //Open it on some event

modal.close(); //This is not needed as you can close it with the modal buttons. It's tricky
```