# Why am I getting this error when I try to open Materialize Modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, materialize

I am trying to display some football fixtures but I am struggling with opening Modals. In each game from each week I want to open one modal where I should display more informations about the respective game. But I get an error in console every time I press any button that should open the modal outside the very first button created. In the Inspect menu I can see that the modals are created and for each modal exist one unique button. But the modals are not displayed on the screen.

### Console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (materialize.js:1146)
at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.jQuery.fn.<computed> [as modal] (materialize.js:1144)
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM3532 etapa:274)
(anonymous) @ materialize.js:1146
each @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
each @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2
jQuery.fn.<computed> @ materialize.js:1144
onclick @ VM3532 etapa:274
```

### PHP code where I echo the modal

```
$i = 1;
$j = 1;
foreach ($games as $rounds) {
    echo "<div id='et$i' class='tabcontent'>";
    echo "<ul class='collection'>";

    foreach ($rounds as $match) {
        echo "<li class='collection-item'>";
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='center col s4'>{$match[1]}</div>";
            echo "<div class='center col s1'>-</div>";
            echo "<div class='center col s4'>{$match[0]}</div>";
            echo "<a href='#meci$j' class='secondary-content' onclick=\"$('#modal$j').modal('open');\"> <i class='material-icons'>assessment</i> </a>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div id='modal$j' class='modal'>";
            echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
            echo "<div class='row'>";
            echo "<div class='center col s4'>$match[1]</div>";
            echo "<div class='center col s1'>-</div>";
            echo "<div class='center col s4'>$match[0]</div>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";
        $j++;
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Laravel's default `app.css` and `app.js` your code works when you remove the word 'open'

```
echo "<a href='#meci$j' class='secondary-content' onclick=\"$('#modal$j').modal('open');\">
```

becomes

```
echo "<a href='#meci$j' class='secondary-content' onclick=\"$('#modal$j').modal();\">
```

Edit: In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086644/2509042) someone mentions that the modals have to be initialized first, for example by using this snippet:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#modal1').modal();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If I remove the 'open' part, I won't get any error when I click the button that open the modal but the first modal will not open .

Comment: The block of code you show is very big. Could you please provide a minimal example that still has the same problem? Also, how are you using the Materialize library, through NPM or Sass or another way? And are you using any other JS libraries alongside Materialize?

Comment: I have changed this:
'echo "<a href='#meci$j' class='secondary-content' onclick=\"$('#modal$j').modal('open');\"> <i class='material-icons'>assessment</i> </a>";'
into this: 
'echo "<a class='modal-trigger secondary-content' href='#modal$j'> <i class='material-icons'>assessment</i></a>";'
And now I don't get that error anymore, but the modals still not opening. I've included the Materialize CDN and install the Materialize files from their site.

Comment: The error is in the materialize.js on the 'instance[methodOrOptions]' line
 // Void methods
      return this.each(function () {
        var instance = this[classRef];
        instance[methodOrOptions].apply(instance, params);
      });

Comment: I expanded my answer. To get the first Modal example on [this page](https://materializecss.com/modals.html) to work I had to initialize the modal first.

Comment: THis worked partially.  If I hard-code the initialization for every modal they are gonna to open. Now I need to initialize dinamically every modal as I create every one of them. Can you suggest me how can I do this? Every modal is created with #modal$j id. I need to  transfer that $j from php to javascript?

Comment: You can place PHP code inside <script> tags to generate JS code, as long as it's within the .php file, about the same way you use PHP code to generate HTML right now.